My code seems correct but my syntax error says I am missing a semicolon
iOS Bundling failed 6688ms node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js (650 modules)
ERROR  SyntaxError: C:\Users\me\Desktop\WeightLiftingApp\App.js: Missing semicolon. (1:4)
This is the code in question:
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

I pasted it into notepad to see if their were any invisible characters causing issues and expected to find some but found nothing

Missing semicolon. (1:4) line one column 4?

i pasted your code but got no error. i think u should reinstall your packages

Do you need to rename the file to App.jsx for it to recognise JSX syntax?

Semicolons are not mandatory in JavaScript. Are you sure it's not a prettier error?
